# How does a diode control direction of current flow in a circuit containg a battery if current in the battery only flows from positive to negative?

Tags: transistors

I think maybe my  question is somewhat too basic for this site.

I am trying to understand the three main functions of a transistor and was confused on the diode function. The book show the N-type P-type interface with a barrier potential.

Although I followed the logic for how the diode controls the direction of current flow the diagrams showed the battery being placed in reversed direction to demonstrate how the diode reversed the flow. This bothers me because I read the flow of current in a typical battery  is from anode to cathode or from positive to negative to begin with.

If this is true then no matter which way the diode is hooked up in the circuit would the current not flow in only one direction to begin with by definition? I think maybe I am obviously missing the main point here.

Comment: There's no such thing as "too basic." Sometimes the best questions are about the basics. I'm just glad your question is actually on topic!

Comment: Please post an image or two, so we can be sure of what the diagram is trying to convey.

Comment: If you think the diode is reversing the direction of flow then you've misunderstood. It allows current to flow one way and prevents it flowing the other.

Comment: @JYelton, actually I agree with the OP, there definitely is a too basic for the site. Questions on fundamentals of electronics or other established areas are much better served by the swathes of pre-written texts and tutorials freely available on the internet, already well-presented with diagrams and honed text. That serves the learner much better than us 'having a go' at rewriting a short version of it again. The site's great for certain things while other things are better on other sites.

Comment: The diode's like a water pipe with a one-way valve in it. Have a search on the internet for 'diode blocks current basics', you'll find tons of well-written webpages already covering this (such as [this one](https://theengineeringmindset.com/the-basics-of-diodes-explained/)).

Comment: @TonyM I see your point. I think something that can be both easily looked up _and_ understood should probably get a pass here. I am, however, a fan of "basic" questions that can receive good explanations that paraphrase technical terms in ways that help capture future searches and novices to the field.

Comment: @JYelton, spot on and I think we're both seeing the same two sides of it. You're right that if a basics explanation here unlocks some confusion that an OP can't get past, or sometimes is just quick and simple, then it's worth doing here, succinctly.

Comment: Sedumjoy, be ***very careful*** when you start bringing chemistry (batteries) into electronics. Chemists call the negative (*reducing*) terminal the **anode** and the positive (*oxidizing*) terminal the **cathode**. Conventional current in electronics goes in a pointed direction from positive to negative. Which from a chemist's view would be from the battery's cathode to its anode, except for the fact that chemists tend to have a nuanced view including differing kinds of charge transfers taking place at the electrode/chemistry barrier with discharge being electrons going from anode to cathode.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.  And I did accept the answer because I believe the illustration in lesson was ill conceived. It makes better sense now. Thank you again.

Comment: Great liink TonyM thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the DC current the single diode can control if the current flow or not. In the study example it can be just an illustration of the diode working. In real cases the single diode can block DC current if the source polarity is reversed, avoiding damage to the device.

But with 4 diodes we can create a device called "diode bridge". A diode bridge can give the fixed polarity at its output regardless of the polarity at its input.